# How to change the contents of a list using a user input variable using Python3

Tags: python, string, list, integer

First, thanks for taking a look at this question. I've been searching everywhere to find the right syntax and I'm out of ideas.

User enters a string which is then saved:

```
strang = input( 'Enter message: ' )
strlen = len( strang )
strang1 = list( strang )
subs = input( 'Enter number between 1-26: ')
```

I created a dictionary to define all the letters of the alphabet so that I could convert the users input string into numbers.

```
dic = { 'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 
'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6,
'g':7, 'h':8, 'i':9,
'j':10, 'k':11, 'l':12,
'm':13, 'n':14, 'o':15,
'p':16, 'q':17, 'r':18,
's':19, 't':20, 'u':21,
'v':22, 'w':23, 'x':24,
'y':25, 'z':26 }
```

I append a crazy value at the end of strang2 so I can select the whole list without that value: strang2[:-1]

```
strang2 = list(dic.get( n, n ) for n in strang1)
strang2.append( 999 )
```

I want to add whatever value the user defines 'subs' as, to the elements of the list 'strang2', convert them back into letters, and print the new string.
The problem is adding subs to the elements of strang2, some kind of data type difference that needs to be resolved. Below code doesn't work right:

```
for iter in strang2:
sum = float( iter + subs )
print( sum )
```

I've been googling and failing for a week, so this is just the last thing I've done so far. Thanks again.

Edit: There were 2 equal signs, erased one. Code returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/User/Scripts!/crypto.py", line 38, in <module>
sum = float( iter + subs )
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: try `subs = int(input( 'Enter number between 1-26: '))`

Comment: Strings are already lists of chars, you don't need to do `strang1 = list(strang)`

Comment: @H.Tacon I think you mean that strings are iterable, thus no list conversion is required for this use case

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes, you are right, I mistaken the concepts with C language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input()` function returns a `str()` type. You're trying to add an int and a string together, which you can't do implicitly because Python is a strongly typed language.

You are also using `sum == float(iter + subs)` which will try and check equality, rather than assign `float(iter + subs)` to `sum`.

To do what it seems like you want to, you need to use `sum = float(iter + int(subs))` - this converts subs to an `int` type, which allows you to add it to iter (also an `int`).

I don't think you need to add a new number to the end of your `strang2` list either, you can use `strang2[:]` to select the whole list.

Comment: Works like a charm. Previously I did a thing similar but I didn't tell subs to be an int. Now everything outputs correctly. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You’re using `sum == float( iter + subs )`. With double `=` you check for a value. So if you use `sum = float( iter + subs )` it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it has returned an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/user/Scripts!/crypto.py", line 38, in <module>
    sum = float( iter + subs )
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: If you’re sure that a number will be inputted, use sum = float(iter + int(subs))

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert both variables to float:

```
sum = float( float(iter) + float(subs ))
```